# Heroku Taps: pushing my DB to heroku gives error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

I get this error:

```
!   Taps >= v0.3.22 is required for this server
```

I have no idea how to fix it.... it seems that everyone has had slightly different problems with taps.

My taps version is 0.3.23

```
> heroku version
heroku-gem/1.18.2

> gem list | grep heroku
heroku (2.2.1)
```

Comment: Do you have the latest version of Heroku gem?

Comment: yes. 1.18.2 of heroku. 2.2.1 of the gem

Comment: do you use rvm? maybe you have the taps installed in a different gemset.

Comment: I don't have rvm =\ error says that it is server side. =\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a guess, but perhaps try running:

> gem update taps

or even removing the gem and installing it again.